# Android onActivityResult() not called

Tags: android

I'm stuck with this problem for 3 hours now and even after reading all answers available on internet i can't find the solution !

I call an activity B (extends FragmentActivity) from an activity A (extends Activity) :

From Activity A, calling Activity B :

```
floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewEventActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        }
    });
```

Nothing scary...

Then in activity B :

```
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putParcelable("event", new MyEvent(eventName.getText().toString(), place.getAddress().toString(), place.getLatLng().latitude, place.getLatLng().longitude, "Test", 4, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
Intent mIntent = new Intent();
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
setResult(2, mIntent);
finish();
```

Here is my onActivityResult() from Activity A where i don't even see the first Log.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("TAG", "onActivityResult, requestCode: " + requestCode + ", resultCode: " + resultCode);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        MyEvent event = data.getExtras().getParcelable("event");
        Log.e("tag", event.getName());
        RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(MainActivity.this, events);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        events.add(event);
        emptyEvents.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

I don't have singleInstance in manifest, i tried to getIntent() in activity B, requestCode is greater than 0, i tried with an intent without extras but none of this worked !

Thank you for your time

Comment: `startActivityForResult` is called in the activity, not in a fragment?

Comment: Called in the activity A :)

Comment: The onActivityResult code is taken from Activity A right?

Comment: Yes it is from activity A

Answer (score 0):

The constant for [RESULT_OK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK) is `-1`, you do

```
setResult(2, mIntent);
```

You would do yourself a favor if you referenced such 'magic numbers' by their constant name like

```
setResult(RSULT_OK, mIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

change 2 to RESULT_OK.

in activity B change

```
 setResult(2, mIntent);
```

to

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
```

and in onActivityResult

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

     if (requestCode == 1) {

        //your code 
     }
}
```

Comment: Tried already but it doesn't work :/
Even a basic log at the first line doesn't show !

Comment: try to set an else statement after first if statement and print a log  to check is there are a problem returning

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you forget this line

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ...
 }
```